# BIOS update removed GRUB from boot options

Tags: dual-boot, 22.10

I updated my BIOS, and after doing so GRUB bootloader completeley vanished from boot options and even windows advanced recovery. Dualboot ubuntu 22.10, windows 11. I cannot access Ubuntu, but the drive still shows in diskmgmt.

Amd ryzen 5 3500U, 12GB ram, vega 8 graphics and 512 gb nvme ssd.
Any help appreciated

Comment: UEFI update often resets to defaults. The settings like RAID to AHCI, Secure Boot, Fast boot or other settings you originally changed may need to be redone. Review UEFI settings.

Comment: We don't know at this point if updating the BIOS just replaced Windows as 1st boot, or whether it removed ubuntu completely from EFI partition, assuming your computer boots in UEFI mode. From Live Ubuntu run *sudo parted -l* and paste output.